# How to have two child components exchange data?

Tags: angular

Conceptually I have the following setup:

```
 AppComponent
      |     \
      |      \
      |   FeedbackComponent
      |
 Router-Outlet
      |
SearchComponent
```

The idea is that when you try to provide feedback using the FeedbackComponent it will collect the current state of the webapp and send it to the server. I'd like to collect from the SearchComponent the latest search that it ran.

In the AppComponent, I have:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

And in the AppComponent view where I use feedback, I have:

```
<feedback [router]="router"></feedback>
```

From the FeedbackComponent, I can then get the name of the currently "routed" component with `this.router.currentInstruction.component.componentType.name` (this returns the string "SearchComponent"). However, `componentType` is the constructor of the object the router is currently pointing to and not the instance of that object. Since I don't have the instance, I can't ask SearchComponent for it's last search without making that query static (which I don't want to do, it breaks other things).

Angular 1 had `$broadcast` and `$emit` but Angular 2 doesn't seem to have a drop in replacement.

If I didn't load the SearchComponent using a Router-Outlet then I could use `@Output()` and `@Input()` to pass things between them through the AppComponent but I don't think I could make that work with the router in that way.

How can an instance of my FeedbackComponent request data from the instance of my SearchComponent?

I'm keeping up to date with Angular2.0.0-beta.13

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service applicable to your case

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 it's using [Services](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) with [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) for communication between components (you can also pass basic data from a parent to child using [@input](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html))

So you want to create a Service, **@Inject** the service in **SearchComponent** set some data in the Service (set.. function) then **@Inject** the service in **FeedbackComponent** and get the data (get... function)

Answer (score 0):

## Service:

```
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";    

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
onGetData: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

getData() {
  this.http.post(...params).map(res => {
    this.onGetData.emit(res.json());
  })
}
```

## Component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';    
import {DataService} from "../services/data.service";       

@Component()
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private DataService:DataService) {
    this.DataService.onGetData.subscribe(res => {
      (from service on .emit() )
    })
  }

  //To send data to all subscribers from current component
  sendData() {
    this.DataService.onGetData.emit(--NEW DATA--);
  }
}
```